# Получение даты из формы PHP

Tags: php, дата

Есть форма

```
<input type="date" required name="date">
```

И есть проблема - при передаче значения этой формы в PHP скрипт у меня функция почему-то выдает boolean, а не DateTime, как должно быть.

```
$adate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['date']);
```

В другом скрипте функция отрабатывает правильно. Если пытаться вывести `$adate`, то мне выводит пустоту, а при выполнении `gettype($adate)` выводит `boolean`

PHP 5.5.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы все равно не можете передать `H:i:s`, поэтому смысл от них:

```
$adate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $_POST['date']);
```

Вариант 2:

```
$adate = date_create('Y-m-d', $_POST['date']);
```

Варик 3:

```
$adate = new DateTime();
$adate->setTimestamp(strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Так будет работать. и P.S. обновите свою пыху ;)

Comment: Без H:i:s мне выдает `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`
P.S. Я бы с радостью обновил, но проект большой и весь написан на этой пыхе. Задолбаюсь все менять :(

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов а что вам приходит в `$_POST['date']`?

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов добавил второй вариант, попробуйте его. А вообще 5.5 и 5.6 в целом совместимы, что вы собрались там переписывать?

Comment: второй вариант ошибки выдает, но я проблему решил. Теперь передается дата. Вот только дата начала всех UNIX-начал. Там ошибку выдавало на место, где я строку с запросом к бд делал. Добавил `$adate = date_format($adate, 'Y-m-d');` и все заработало. Но мне тоже не 0 по UNIX нужен)
Насчет 5.6 не знаю, но с 7 версией у меня все функции обращения к базе падают.

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов 5.6 и 7 не совместимы. а вот 5.5 и 5.6 должны быть

Comment: а не подскажете, что делать с датой, чтоб она в зеро не уходила?

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов я не совсем понимаю, что у вас там происходит поэтому сложно сказать в чем именно вам помочь, отредактируйте вопрос, покажите что у вас сейчас и что не так. И желательно покажите все-таки что вам приходит в `$_POST['date']`

Comment: Сейчас - `$adate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date']));
  echo gettype($adate);
  $adate = date_format($adate, 'Y-m-d');
  $query = "INSERT INTO 'users'('tgname', 'expire_date', 'group') VALUES ('$nickname','$adate' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'$tggroup')";` В `$_POST['date'] приходит дата в виде `yyyy-mm-dd'. Ее выводил, все нормально. Тип - string

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов костыли на ровном месте -.- `date` так не работает, попробуй тогда уж `$adate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date'])));`

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов добавил 3ий варик.

Comment: да, это все мои костыли виноваты, ибо я не умею считать строки) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

у Вас из поля ввода данные приходят в виде 2018-06-26 (Y-m-d)

а форматируете Вы их в виде Y-m-d H:i:s, т.е. часов, минут, секунд форма не отдает, потому функция честно отдает false

Comment: Без H:i:s мне выдает `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`